# mongodb updateMany with $in and arrayFilters

Tags: mongodb

I have following collection structure:

```
{
   _id: userId,
   posts: [{ _id: postId, views: 0 }]
}
```

My input are following:

1. Array with user IDs
2. Array with post IDs

With that information i want to increment the `views` for every user / post that matches, i have tried it like this:

```
await Post.updateMany(
    {
      _id: {
        $in: userIds
      }
    },
    {
      $inc: {
        "posts.$[elem].views": 1
      }
    },
    {
      arrayFilters: [
        {
          "elem._id": {
            $in: postIds
          }
        }
      ],
      upsert: true
    }
  );
```

But i got the error:

> The array filter for identifier 'elem' was not used in the update {
>   $setOnInsert: { __v: 0 } }

I also made sure that the IDs are ObjectIds and not strings.

So what did i wrong here?

Comment: What documentation are you following?

Comment: @Oleg the official documentation from mongodb

Comment: @Ifaruki your syntax looks alright, have you checked that `$[<identifier>]` is compatible with your MongoDB version?

Comment: @thammada i have the lastes mongodb version, and i have used that indentifier already, but not in `updateMany`, i have used it in `findeOneAndModify` but isnt the problem, or is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that query works fine, i just forgott to add the property `views` to my mongoose model

After adding `views` to my model it worked

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
  },
  posts: [
    {
      _id: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
      },
      userid: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
      },
      images: {
        type: Object
      },
      category: {
        type: String
      },
      description: {
        type: String
      },
      hashtags: {
        type: Array
      },
      comments: {
        type: Array
      },
      likesUser: {
        type: Array
      },
      time: {
        type: Number
      },
      loading: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
      },
      views: {
        type: Number
      }
    }
  ]
});
```